# kill pid is not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, kill

This is pretty weird now. I am trying to kill a process by using its `pid` but it is not working at all.

```
root@machineA:/home/david# ps aux | grep modelling
david  5075  0.0  0.0 1285420 29404 ?       Dl   21:05   0:01 /opt/modelling/bin/http
root   8730  0.0  0.0   8096   936 pts/4    S+   22:43   0:00 grep --color=auto modelling
```

Below is the way I am kiiling the process.

```
root@machineA:/home/david# kill -9 5075
```

And then if I do the `ps` again. I can see the same result back again.

```
root@machineA:/home/david# ps aux | grep modelling
david  5075  0.0  0.0 1285420 29404 ?       Dl   21:05   0:01 /opt/modelling/bin/http
root   9062  0.0  0.0   8100   936 pts/4    S+   22:44   0:00 grep --color=auto modelling
```

Does anyone know what is happening? This was working fine earlier and it has started happening few hours back and I am not sure what's wrong?

**Update:-**

I did top and it is showing as `D` instead of `Z` which is `uninterruptible sleep`

```
5075 david  20   0 1255m  28m  13m D    0  0.0   0:01.09 http
```

Comment: Here is a copy-pasted link to a copy-pasted answer I did yesterday about this very thing: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134899/52934

Answer (score 2):

To remove a `D State` Process, since it is uninterruptible, *only a machine reboot can solve the problem* in case its not automatically handled by the system.

Usually there is a very few chance that a process stays in `D State` for long. And if it does then there is something not properly being handled in the system. This can be a potential bug as well.

Below is an extract from OpenVZ about what is `D State` of a process.

> D state occurs then the process is in uninterruptible sleep. This
>   state is bad, because you can't do anything with the process in D
>   state. Fortunately, process normally remains in such state not for so
>   long. But if you have a heap of D state processes then some logic in
>   system is disrupt. If that is happening, the very important thing is
>   to determine where this unlucky sleep occurs. It is easy to do with ps
>   command with l option. WCHAN column shows the name of the kernel
>   function where the process is sleeping:

```
# ps axl | awk '$10 ~ /D/'
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
vass     13478  7.2  0.0   1732   624 pts/1    D+   17:36   0:00 find ./
```

[Refernce] - https://openvz.org/Processes_in_D_state