# Execute command or function when SIGINT or SIGTERM is send to the parent script itself, not the child processes

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, process, signals

Let's say I have this `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    echo "Maybe executing other commands!"
    kill -- -$$ # Sends SIGTERM to child/sub processes
}

echo "Some other text"
#other commands here
sleep infinity
```

I want `script.sh` to execute the function `exit_script` whenever it receives `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`
For example:

```
killall script.sh # it will send SIGTERM to my script
```

and I want my script to execute this

```
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    echo "Maybe executing other commands!"
    kill -- -$$ # Sends SIGTERM to child/sub processes
}
```

I tried to implement this feature using `trap`

```
trap exit_script SIGINT SIGTERM
```

The person who answered my question proved me wrong.
<strike>but it didn't work because `trap` seems to react only to signals sent to child/sub processes. As a beginner I couldn't decipher `trap`'s man page so I probably missed the solution.</strike>

I guess that's what "real" programs like Chromium do when you send them `SIGTERM`

From https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

> The application can determine what it wants to do once a SIGTERM is
>   received. While most applications will clean up their resources and
>   stop, some may not.

Comment: generally swears are considered inapproriate for respectful discourse

Comment: edit suggestion approved ok, ok done, no fun I get it

Comment: it's not that no fun is allowed, it's just that's considered offensive

Comment: @cat I've thought about your argument and you are right, sorry for my tomfoolery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`trap` reacts to the calling process signals itself. But you must call it before the signal is received. I mean, at the beginning of your script.

Furthermore, if you want to use `kill -- -$$`, which sends the signal also to your script, you need to clear the trap before running the kill or you will end with an infinite *kill && trap* loop.

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    echo "Maybe executing other commands!"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM # clear the trap
    kill -- -$$ # Sends SIGTERM to child/sub processes
}

trap exit_script SIGINT SIGTERM

echo "Some other text"
#other commands here
sleep infinity
```

As explained in the comments, the problem is that the script receives the signal but is waiting for the sleep program to end before processing the received signal. So, you should kill the child processes (the sleep process in this case) in order run the trap action. You can do that with something like the following:

```
kill -- -$(pgrep script.sh)
```

Or as stated in the comments:

```
killall -g script.sh
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something because it doesn't work, here is what I do.   script.sh &; killall script.sh     but it does nothing.

Comment: I execute the script.sh &; # then I do my business; killall script.sh and it doesn't kill script.sh

Comment: The problem probably is that the script receives the signal but is waiting for the sleep program to end before processing it. Try with `./script.sh & sleep 1 && kill -- -$(pgrep script.sh)` to send a kill signal also to the child processes of your script.

Comment: @zuazo You should add this interesting and important information to your answer :)

Comment: @zuazo I found an even simpler way `script.sh &;# other commands I may run; killall -g script.sh`   (the -g is for --process-group)

Comment: Nice, bosa djo. I added your alternative solution to the answer ;-)